# Advantages of Geohashing

Tags: geohashing

Can someone explain what are positives of using geohashing?
Why not split the map in squares of some size and each square has x,y index and we can keep a map from the index of the square to the data in it. This way it's easier to find data in some region or do k-nearest query.

Answer (score 0):

Geohashing allows for arbitrary precision. You can geohash a quadrant and then search for all points within the hashed quadrant. If my reading is correct this should return a hash table in constant time [O(1)]. Indexing a map is inflexible. If you want to search a subspace of a quadrant or parts of two adjacent quadrants, you'll have to search all your data again unless you've sorted the data in each quadrant which would be linear time [O(n)].